# Firebase Rules Configuration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Implement user level data setup using the sample given in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules
Want to implement read/write access only at user level keeping read only rule intact on other nodes.

**Final Rule written as**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}
```

**Sample database structure**

Want to provide read / write access only to users node not others.

Sample JSON Data

```
{
   "zmjilhwtlo":{
      "MapData":[
         {
            "CaseId":"1",
            "SectionId":"1"
         },
         {
            "CaseId":"2",
            "SectionId":"2"
         }
      ],
      "MapDataRoot":[
         {
            "SrNo":"1",
            "IsFav":"0",
            "ChapterNo":"data",
            "ChapterName":"dad",
            "ActId":"dfd",
            "SectionName":"dfd",
            "Description":"dfd"
         }
      ]
   },
   "hvbxaotcxw":{
      "MapData":[
         {
            "CaseId":"1",
            "SectionId":"1"
         },
         {
            "CaseId":"2",
            "SectionId":"2"
         }
      ],
      "MapDataRoot":[
         {
            "SrNo":"1",
            "IsFav":"0",
            "ChapterNo":"data",
            "ChapterName":"dad",
            "ActId":"dfd",
            "SectionName":"dfd",
            "Description":"dfd"
         }
      ]
   },
   "aundpytdod":{
      "MapData":[
         {
            "CaseId":"1",
            "SectionId":"1"
         },
         {
            "CaseId":"2",
            "SectionId":"2"
         }
      ],
      "MapDataRoot":[
         {
            "SrNo":"1",
            "IsFav":"0",
            "ChapterNo":"data",
            "ChapterName":"dad",
            "ActId":"dfd",
            "SectionName":"dfd",
            "Description":"dfd"
         }
      ]
   },
   "embpkeanaj":{
      "MapData":[
         {
            "CaseId":"1",
            "SectionId":"1"
         },
         {
            "CaseId":"2",
            "SectionId":"2"
         }
      ],
      "MapDataRoot":[
         {
            "SrNo":"1",
            "IsFav":"0",
            "ChapterNo":"data",
            "ChapterName":"dad",
            "ActId":"dfd",
            "SectionName":"dfd",
            "Description":"dfd"
         }
      ]
   },
   "users":{

   }
}
```

Error screenshots from simulator
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo - updated question with database structure

Comment: I cannot see in your schema, the `users` node and the corresponding uid's beheath it. Can you please add a more specific one?

Comment: users node is at same level of other nodes.. updated question with sample structure

Comment: Please add a sample of your user node.

Comment: @AlexMamo - Updated question with sample data. So basically we want to give just access to users node read/write. Other nodes should only have read access

Comment: You are creating Firebase rules for a node which contains no informations.

Comment: Please clean up your question a bit, and only include the minimum need to reproduce the problem. In this case that is: 1) the rules you are using, 2) the JSON you are writing (both as text, no screenshots please), and 3) a screenshot of the simulator showing the path you write, the data you write, and the auth configuration you specified.

Comment: @AlexMamo -  empty node is not an issue. See above screenshot if you change rule write = true. I'm able to test

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Updated my question with screenshots

Comment: The fact that the write to `/users` is denied looks correct to me. Nobody has write permission to `/users`. Each individual user only has write access to `/users/$theiruid`, so you should write to that for it to be allowed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - How can i test that in simulator? I don't see an option to send uid? I'm missing any parameters?. If I allow write = true on global level it allows me to write inside users without providing uuid

Comment: You just write to the path of the UID that you use in the test, so `/users/e32bcdf5....`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Yesssss.. that works.. so i assume I have written the rule correctly... thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your security rules don't allow anyone to write to `/users`, the write to `/users` that you're trying in the emulator is correct rejected. If you want to see if a user can write their own node, you'll want to write to `/users/e32bcdf5....` (or whatever their UID is).